# SQL Query when where clause could be empty or contain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like a select query that would be able to select a value that may or may not be present in the where clause.  Schema:

```
----------------------------------
studentid|firstname|lastname|major
```

My select clause would be

```
select * from students where studentid?={param} AND firstname?={param} AND lastname?={param} AND major?={param};
```

I put a question mark because I mean to say I could pass a value in the where clause or I might not.  It could be

```
select * from students where studentid?=34344 AND firstname?="john" AND lastname?="smith" AND major?="";

select * from students where studentid?=34344 AND firstname?="john" AND lastname?="smith" AND major?="english";
```

Is there a way to do this easily without a stored procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using variables and checking null like this:

```sql
Declare @StudentId nvarchar(100) --can be null or evaluated

select * from students 
where (@StudentId is null or studnetId= @StudentId) AND -- for other properties as well
```

Another option is using dynamic sql and first you have to build your sql query and then execute it (I don't like it)

You can handle it in the application side if possible:

```cs
string query= "select * from students where 1=1 /*trick for adding more conditions*/"

if(numberId is not null)
   query += "AND studentId= {numberId} ";

//for other conditions ...
```

Comment: I don't have to declare @studentid nvarchar(100) do I? I  can't use this query with my own variables is C# code.  int numberID = 34343 ie: select * from students 
where (studentID is "" or studentID= numberID)? Is this possible

Comment: If you want to handle it in application side, it's better to build the query and check if the propery has evaluated then add it to where clause like ``if(numberId is not null) query+= "StudentId= {numberId}"``

Comment: @questionsneedanswers Answer updated for application side

Comment: agreed very true. Thank you. Question answered